# how put new odoo modules from git development version to production version (installed by logithèque ubuntu)?

Tags: git, ubuntu, odoo

All procedure to clone git odoo development project are done perfectly. but i don’t find many important files like : web, server,..!
why?
Beside,I install the production part using logithèque ubuntu 14.04 ,then files are dispatched in many locations in the pc. and if i want to update a new module from developer version to productive version (add path of new addons for productive version) nothing changed : my new modules don’t appear in list to install! so the question how can i put my new modules from development version to production version (installed by logithèque ubuntu)? thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

so, i find it.
Just must activate the technical characteristic in user form to get button of update modules.